# C# - GetMethod returns null

Tags: c#

I have `A` class:

```
public abstract class A
{

}
```

And then I have `B` class that derives from it:

```
public sealed class B : A
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("AddText");
    }

    private void AddText(string text)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why is `GetMethod` returning null?

Comment: Note that if you just mouse over `GetMethod(...)` in Visual Studio, it clearly states `Searches for the **public** method with the specified name.` It's obvious to me from just that message that another overload is required.

Comment: but why not just call `AddText`?

Comment: @Grundy, probably because this is just a toy problem that illustrates the real issue. So whether there is a more direct way of doing something is irrelevant here

Comment: @Graviton, probably, but you can't be sure :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("AddText", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
```

Your method has a parameter, you need to use the overload that accepts a type array for the parameter types and the binding flags.

In .net Method signatures are based on their name, their return type, and their parameters.

So if your method has parameters you have to tell Reflection what parameter types it has via a Type[].

Comment: Actually, as long as there aren't multiple overloads, you can just specify the name.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you! The 'BindingFlags.Instance' modifier was missing, so that's why the search failed!

Comment: If your method was static, then you would need to remove the BindingFlags.Instance method.  However I am curious why you need reflection, theres a good chance the new Func<>, or Action<> features will solve your problem.

Comment: @Slaks, True, but it's good practice to do it because if someone adds an overload down the road, then the code could break.

Answer (score 22):

By default, Reflection will only search for public methods.

You need to pass `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Comment: I tried using the BindingFlags and it still returns null.

Comment: Your method has a parameter, you need to use the overload that accepts a type array for the parameter types and the binding flags.  GetMehtod by default returns a public method with no parameters.

Due to method overloading you need to tell reflection which method parameter signature to get.

Comment: @Jashaszun I just tested it as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryios I tried removing the arguments used by AddText, leaving it with no parameters. It still returns null.

Comment: Are you by chance doing this on Mono or .Net Core 5?

Comment: Also, why do you need to do this?  You can store methods to delegates and call those, you can even create inline methods you can call over and over again from inside a method.